# Pester Should -Throw does not catch error

Tags: powershell, pester, pester-5

This is the same problem and solution as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60846620/pester-test-is-failing-when-and-expected-error-is-thrown), but with simpler examples and hopefully easier to find, since it took me hours to find the above question.

I have the following code that I want to test:

```
Test-Function(){
  {...}
  if($ExitCode -ne 0){
    throw "Stopped with exit code $ExitCode"
  }
}
```

I am trying to test it using this:

```
It "Testing"{
  Test-Function -Bad "Params" | Should -Throw
}
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
   [-] Testing 1.03s (1.03s|2ms)
    RuntimeException: Stopped with exit code 10
    At Test-Function {...}
```

I already tried using the exact error message in `Should -Throw` and using Write-Error instead of throwing. None of those worked for me

Comment: [Pester documentation](https://pester-docs.netlify.app/docs/v4/usage/assertions#throw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When testing for `Should -Throw`, the code must be inside of a script block, so it should look like this:

```
It "Testing"{
  {Test-Function -Bad "Params"} | Should -Throw
}
```

Comment: Looks like a lambda.